# Trigger Update SQL server para tabla historica

Tags: sql-server, trigger, update

tengo un problema con mi trigger for update, tengo la tabla equipo y la tabla historico_stock_xbodega, en la cual mi tabla equipo le desarrolle un trigger update que me inserte todos los datos modificados en la tabla historico_stock_xbodega, pero al insertar los registros me inserta 3 mas entre ellos dos registros NULL. La verdad no se me ocurre en que puedo estar fallando dentro del trigger.

imagen de tabla historico_stock_xbodega al actualizar un solo registro y campo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

estructura trigger:

```
 SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
        alter trigger [dbo].[tr_actualizar_equipo]
        on [dbo].[equipo] for update
        AS
        set nocount on
        
        declare @id_equipo int
        declare @crea_por nvarchar (30)
        declare @n_serie nvarchar (80)
        declare @cod_estado nvarchar (40)
        declare @n_referencia nvarchar (50)
        declare @cod_categoria nvarchar (40)
        declare @cod_marca nvarchar (40)
        declare @cod_modelo nvarchar (40)
        declare @cod_compania nvarchar (40)
        declare @cod_proyecto nvarchar(40)
        declare @cod_area nvarchar (40) 
    
        select @id_equipo = id_equipo from inserted
        select @crea_por = crea_por from inserted
        select @n_serie = n_serie from inserted
        select @cod_estado = cod_estado from inserted
        select @n_referencia = n_referencia from inserted
        select @cod_categoria = cod_categoria from inserted
        select @cod_marca = cod_marca from inserted
        select @cod_modelo = cod_modelo from inserted
        select @cod_compania = cod_compania from inserted
        select @cod_proyecto = cod_proyecto from inserted
        select @cod_area = cod_area from inserted
    
        insert into historial_stock_xbodega values (@id_equipo, @crea_por, GETDATE(),  @n_serie, @cod_estado,
        @n_referencia, @cod_categoria, @cod_marca, @cod_modelo, @cod_compania, @cod_proyecto, @cod_area, '')
```

Estructura tabla equipo:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[equipo](
    [n_serie] [nvarchar](80) NOT NULL,
    [cod_categoria] [nvarchar](40) NOT NULL,
    [cod_marca] [nvarchar](40) NOT NULL,
    [cod_modelo] [nvarchar](40) NOT NULL,
    [nro_oc] [nvarchar](40) NULL,
    [fecha_compra] [datetime] NULL,
    [cod_compania] [nvarchar](40) NULL,
    [cod_proyecto] [nvarchar](40) NULL,
    [cod_area] [nvarchar](40) NULL,
    [fecha_fue_servicio] [datetime] NULL,
    [observaciones] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [crea_por] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
    [fecha_actualizacion] [datetime] NULL,
    [actualizado_por] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
    [fecha_creacion] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [fuera_service] [nvarchar](40) NOT NULL,
    [id_equipo] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [cod_estado] [nvarchar](40) NOT NULL,
    [n_referencia] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id_equipo] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El trigger esta mal planteado, porque utiliza la pseudo-tabla inserted como si solo fuera posible insertar un registro de cada vez, y no es así. Se pueden insertar varios registros en la misma sentencia. Tienes que reconducirlo a un trigger que trabaje con conjuntos.

Una opción simple.

```
create or alter trigger [dbo].[tr_actualizar_equipo]
on [dbo].[equipo] for update
AS
Set nocount on

insert into historial_stock_xbodega 
-- pon entre paréntesis los nombres de los campos de la tabla
-- historial_stock_xbodega que corresponden con los datos.
--(id_equipo, creada_por, [fecha], no se como se llama, por eso no lo pongo yo.
Select id_equipo,   crea_por, GetDate(), n_serie, cod_estado, n_referencia,
cod_categoria, cod_marca, cod_odelo, cod_compania, cod_proyecto, cod_area, ''
From inserted;
```

[Trigger for update. ¿Cómo funciona?](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2020/04/15/trigger-que-es-como-se-hace-y-como-funciona-after-for-update/)

Comment: Si tu versión del motor es anterior a 2016, tendrás que cambiar además la definición de la cabecera del trigger, donde he puesto `create or alter`, será solo `Alter`

Comment: Si necesitas más información sobre porque puede fallar el trigger, en mi opinión la respuesta está en el uso de las variables. Una declaración de variable que lee datos en un trigger, no tiene ni idea sobre que fila esta accediendo del conjunto. Hay más info de este error en este hilo del blog de Brent Ozar con la base de datos de stack overflow. [The silent bug I Find in Most Triggers](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/05/the-silent-bug-i-find-in-most-triggers/)

Comment: Javi fer2, lo intente con la sentencia que me dejaste, me pasa exactamente lo mismo que con la anterior, pero luego probé con instead of update from inserted dando el resultado que quería, gracias por la iluminacion compadre: 
create trigger [dbo].[tr_actualizar_equipo]
on [dbo].[equipo] instead of update
AS
Set nocount on
insert into historial_stock_xbodega 
Select (id_equipo), (crea_por), (GetDate()), (n_serie), (cod_estado), (n_referencia),
(cod_categoria), (cod_marca), (cod_modelo), (cod_compania), (cod_proyecto), (cod_area), ('')
From inserted;